# Transfering encrypted files via FTP, corrupted when decrypted

Tags: c#, ftp

Using the code below I'm trying to upload an encrypted file to an FTP server.
When downloading the files from the ftp server, they're all corrupted.

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
    user, 
    pass);

StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(tempfilepath);
byte[] fileContents = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd()); // uploads corrupted files
//byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(tempfilepath);
sourceStream.Close();
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
requestStream.Close();

// Shows confirm message
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();
```

Any clue what could be the problem?

Comment: Don't roundtrip to ASCII. That corrupts all bytes >127.

Comment: Uncomment `byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(tempfilepath);`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're reading arbitrary binary data into a `StreamReader`.
Don't do that.

`StreamReader`s read text; passing raw binary data into a StreamReader will drop all invalid code points.

Instead, you should work purely with `Stream` or `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved... Unfortunately it was a very dumb problem so it won't really help anyone.
I was actually uploading the unencrypted file, so when I decrypt it, obviously it's not gonna work.